# Left align last menu item in 3 label deep dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a dropdown menu and if the the last menu item on level 1 has 3 level deep dropdown sub-menu then the third level didn't show up because all the sub-menu is displaying left to right .

I want the last menu item to be displayed its sub-menu item from right to left ... I have searched but couldn't find a suitable answer.

I have posted sample code in jsfiddle and in that fiddle the `{M-2}Level 1` have sub-menu `Level-2-1` and it has a sub-menu `Level 3-1` . I want the `Level 3-1` to be displayed in the left side of `Level-2-1`. I mean it should be right to left instead of left to right.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>{M-1}Level 1
            <ul>
                <li>Level 2-1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Level 3-1</li>
                        <li>Level 3-2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>{M-2}Level 1 
        <ul>
                <li>Level 2-1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Level 3-1</li>
                        <li>Level 3-2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**and the CSS:**

```
#nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav ul li{
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 20px;
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    background-color:#EEE;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
#nav li > ul{
    visibility:hidden;
    width:200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:200px;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul{
    top:50px;
    left:0;
}
#nav li:hover{
    background-color:#999;
}
#nav li:hover > ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yb4aL/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **:last-child** pseudoclass, you can pull this off with the addition of one more rule.

```
#nav > ul > li:last-child > ul > li > ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
}
```

[Here's an updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Cwr/).

Answer (score 0):

have a class like .leftAlign and just plug that in wherever you want, try not to specify your css too much, think modular.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav > ul > li > ul {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yb4aL/10/